# I need to wrap a substitute variable in double quotes in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am echoing a string and directing it to a text file and in echoed string I need variable substitution which needs to encoded in double-quotes tried a couple of ways but unable to get it.

```
PASSWORD = XYZ
echo 'password =' \"'"$PASSWORD"'\" > form.txt
cat form.txt
password ='XYZ' # what I am getting
password ="XYZ" # what I am needed
```

Comment: Under [tag:bash] `PASSWORD = XYZ` won't work, because of space around equal sign! Must be written: `PASSWORD=XYZ`. Please post question without rewriting your code!

Comment: ... Then use: `printf 'password = "%s"\n' "$PASSWORD"` for your need. And please read manpages before asking

Comment: ... And don't take habit of storing secrets in environment.

Comment: With your code I get `password = ""$PASSWORD""` instead of `password ='XYZ'`. Maybe the question doesn't show your original code.

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways. 
One can be

```
PASSWORD=XYZ  
echo "password=\"$PASSWORD\"" > form.txt
```

P.S. Of course, you know that storing password in file is usually a bad idea...

Answer (score 2):

You can just escape `"` where you need them to be evaluated as `char` and omit spaces:

```
PASSWORD=XYZ
echo 'password ='\""$PASSWORD"\" > form.txt
```

Comment: The first line of your code will generate an error, blanks before and after the equal sign are not allowed in bash